# Como ocultar e reexibir barra de tarefas em C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Quero que minha aplicação possua um botão que oculte e reexiba a barra de tarefas do Windows em C#, para bloquear acesso do usuário a mesma. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes: porque, pra que... Já pesquisou algo? Isso é bem complicado. Por exemplo mesmo que você mate o processo Explorer.exe que irá ocultar a barra de tarefas, isso não te garante que o usuário não irá pressionar Windows + R e abrir o Explorer novamente.

Comment: A ideia é que a aplicação possa bloquear o acesso do usuário a barra de tarefas (como apertar f11 nos navegadores). Daí pensei em duas possibilidades que seria o controle de exibição da barra de tarefas ou fazer com que a aplicação fique "por cima" da mesma, impossibilitando o acesso. Pesquisei bastante, encontrei algumas coisas como utilizar borderStyle, mas estou tendo problemas para implementar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como disseram, é bem complicado fazer, porém não impossível.
Adicione uma nova classe com o seguinte código:

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
public class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentHandle, int childAfter, string className, int windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    protected static int Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        }
    }

    protected static int HandleOfStartButton
    {
        get
        {
            int handleOfDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
            int handleOfStartButton = FindWindowEx(handleOfDesktop, 0, "button", 0);
            return handleOfStartButton;
        }
    }

    private Taskbar()
    {
        // hide ctor
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_SHOW);
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

Show() mostra e Hide() oculta.

Answer (score 3):

Ocultar a reexibir a tarefa é uma coisa bem complicada, principalmente porque não é algo que as aplicações simplesmente possam sair por aí fazendo. Senão seria fácil fazer isso virar bagunça.

O que você quer, é manter a tela da sua aplicação em *full screen* e isso é **muito simples**. Só é necessário maximizar o *form*, remover as bordas e definir a propriedade `TopMost` como `true`.

Exemplo:

```
// colocar o form em full screen
private void btFullScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TopMost = true;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}

// Voltar ao estado normal (barra tarefas aparecendo)
private void btRestaurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TopMost = false;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle; // ou a que estava antes
}
```